# Merge ObservableCollections not creating new collection

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I need merge two `sorted` collections

```
var collection1 = new ObservableCollection<T>();
var collection2 = new ObservableCollection<T>();
```

One of collection binding to `ItemsSource` property of `ListView`.

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding collection1}" />
```

Can be used `Union`

```
collection1 = new ObservableCollection<T>(Followers.Union(collection2, new Comparer()));
```

But in this case two problems:

1) `Union()` return `IEnumerable<T>`, in other words new `Collection`. But I need update collection1, not creating new collection, to avoid blink on the UI.

2) Doesn't update properties of elements from `collection1`. But it not critical, of secondary importance.

I can not think of a better solution than to walk on each collection and the first pass to add new items in the second to remove excess.

How resolve this problem, merge collections and avoid blink on the UI (not create new collection)?

Comment: yeas, and remove all elements from collection1 which not contains collection2.